# WCF Client Proxies, Client/Channel Caching in ASP.Net - Code Review

Tags: asp.net, wcf, proxy, client, channelfactory

long time ASP.Net interface developer being asked to learn WCF, looking for some education on more architecture related fronts - as its not my strong suit but I'm having to deal.

In our current ASMX world we adopted a model of creating ServiceManager static classes for our interaction with web services.  We're starting to migrate to WCF, attempting to follow the same model.  At first I was dealing with performance problems, but I've tweaked a bit and we're running smoothly now, but I'm questioning my tactics.  Here's a simplified version (removed error handling, caching, object manipulation, etc.) of what we're doing:

```
public static class ContentManager
{
    private static StoryManagerClient _clientProxy = null;
    const string _contentServiceResourceCode = "StorySvc";

    // FOR CACHING
    const int _getStoriesTTL = 300;
    private static Dictionary<string, GetStoriesCacheItem> _getStoriesCache = new Dictionary<string, GetStoriesCacheItem>();
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _cacheLockStories = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static Story[] GetStories(string categoryGuid)
    {
        // OMITTED - if category is cached and not expired, return from cache

        // get endpoint address from FinderClient (ResourceManagement SVC)
        UrlResource ur = FinderClient.GetUrlResource(_contentServiceResourceCode);

        // Get proxy
        StoryManagerClient svc = GetStoryServiceClient(ur.Url);

        // create request params
        GetStoriesRequest request = new GetStoriesRequest{}; // SIMPLIFIED
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest{}; // SIMPLIFIED

        // execute GetStories at WCF service
        try
        {
            GetStoriesResponse response = svc.GetStories(manifest, request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (svc.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                svc.Abort();
            }

            throw;
        }

        // OMITTED - do stuff with response, cache if needed
        // return....
    }

    internal static StoryManagerClient GetStoryServiceClient(string endpointAddress)
    {
        if (_clientProxy == null)
            _clientProxy = new StoryManagerClient(GetServiceBinding(_contentServiceResourceCode), new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));

        return _clientProxy;
    }

    public static Binding GetServiceBinding(string bindingSettingName)
    {
        // uses Finder service to load a binding object - our alternative to definition in web.config
    }

    public static void PreloadContentServiceClient()
    {
        // get finder location
        UrlResource ur = FinderClient.GetUrlResource(_contentServiceResourceCode);

        // preload proxy
        GetStoryServiceClient(ur.Url);
    }    
}
```

We're running smoothly now with round-trip calls completing in the 100ms range.  Creating the PreloadContentServiceClient() method and adding to our global.asax got that "first call" performance down to that same level. And you might want to know we're using the DataContractSerializer, and the "Add Service Reference" method.

I've done a lot of reading on static classes, singletons, shared data contract assemblies, how to use the ChannelFactory pattern and a whole bunch of other things that I could do to our usage model...admittedly, some of its gone over my head.  And, like I said, we seem to be running smoothly.  I know I'm not seeing the big picture, though.  Can someone tell me what I've ended up here with regards to channel pooling, proxy failures, etc. and why I should head down the ChannelFactory path?  My gut says to just do it, but my head can't comprehend why...

Thanks!

Comment: You should include your exception handling code in your question because it is pertinent for WCF proxies. See this [blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) for a brief overview of necessary logic for exception handling. Also, try creating a load test of your app with the WCF service & client changed to use the netTcpBinding in your config. If anything will smoke out improper disposal of WCF proxies is sustained load with the netTcpBinding.

Comment: I just added the try/catch block around the service operation in the code above.  Nothing fancy at this point.  One thing I noticed in the blog post you linked was the use of client.Close() after the operation was completed.  If I were to close the client, does that defeat the purpose having a channel all ready to go to speed up the next call?

Comment: Microsoft made certain design decisions in implementing IDisposable for the WCF channels that require a usage pattern similar to my  referenced one so network resources are properly released. If your WCF service is called by clients with a few requests per minute, then you can usually get away with allowing the .NET GC to eventually recover the resources. You should read this [blog post for a good discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/03/18/avoiding-problems-with-the-using-statement-and-wcf-service-proxies.aspx) of this issue, follow the links in it to get the full story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) is typically used when you aren't using **Add Service Reference** - you have the contract via a shared assembly not generated via a WSDL. **Add Service Reference** uses [`ClientBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx) which is essentially creating the WCF channel for you behind the scenes.

When you are dealing with REST-ful services, [`WebChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908674.aspx) provides a service-client like interface based off the shared assembly contract. You can't use **Add Service Reference** if your service only supports a REST-ful endpoint binding.

The only difference to you is preference - do you need full access the channel for custom behaviors, bindings, etc. or does **Add Service Reference** + SOAP supply you with enough of an interface for your needs.

Comment: We like the model of using Request and Response objects for each of our method calls.  It makes it easy to keep services backwards compatible without having to upgrade all instances of the client at once...like adding another filter to a request object or an additional field to the response.  If both methods can be used to achieve similar outputs, then we'd prefer to not have typed, shared data contracts.  And no need for REST here, yet at least...